# Establishing the isomorphism between a vector space of $n\times n$ real matrices and $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

I am a physics student and this question mostly pertains to trying to understand the tensor product. I'm trying to see the relationship between column vector and matrix forms of the tensor product of two vectors.

My question is this, when we take the vector space $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and want to show it is isomorphic to the vector space of $n\times n$ real matrices, does it matter which component in the vector is mapped to which component in the matrix?

As an example, say I want to define a relationship between $v\in \Bbb R^4$ and the corresponding $2\times 2$ real matrix under the isomorphism, is the map: $$I:v_i\mapsto M_{jk},\quad i=1,2,3,4,\quad j,k=1,2$$ equivalent for all $i$,$j$ and $k$ if the *only* thing we are interested in preserving is the linear structure? Assuming it is 1-to-1 and performed the same way for all elements of $V$.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the mapping of components to entries in the matrix is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: @philbo_baggins Thanks for the response, is this also true even if we plan to treat the matrix as an element of the tensor space $V\otimes V$ for instance, as in [this section of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps), the entries are put in a very specific order when $A$ and $B$ are applied to the tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

Let $i=nq+r$ where $0\le r\le n-1$, then $v_i\mapsto M_{q+1,r+1}$.